# Three.js default rotation with trackball control

Tags: rotation, webgl, three.js, trackball

I have a scene with several meshes in three.js The distance between the meshes is fixed. The problem is that the whole group is upside down. My first thought would be to rotate the camera  over the z-axis with pi. This does't work because the trackball controls that I used reset this rotation. Is there a way to override the default rotation?

Comment: Can you post your scene's code by chance? I have a few demos where I use the trackball controls and it seems like I may have had similar problems at first, but I just checked and it seems my rotations are OK by default.

Comment: @CoryGross Posting my code is somewhat difficult since it is a very big project. But I have found a solution (sort off). When I do `camera.up.set(0, -1, 0)` I get the rotation. It introduces another problem though. I have a [tween](https://github.com/sole/tween.js) to reset the camera to its initial position. It resets the position and rotation. This worked fine before, but now its all messed up. Maybe it is better to rotate the whole group of meshes initially. I have centered all meshes as described [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1911). Any idea how to rotate the group?

Comment: Stuck the same way. Have you found the solution?